# Application Insight : Javascript SDK

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have noticed that the user location reported via Application Insight is very unreliable.
It is reporting my location in different state, Whereas when using WhatisMyIP it is able to accurately report my location.

Why such a difference with Application Insight ?

Here is what Appliction Insight Reports:
[image]

Here is the accurate location reported by WhatIsMyIP

[image]

Comment: Is there any proxy used?

Comment: No, but why would WhatisMyIp report it correctly in case i was using it ? 
I was accessing website from Home when i noticed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application insights uses the [GeoLite2 from MaxMind for IP and geolocation lookup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ip-collection#default-behavior).

And I tested it at my side by using [GeoLite2](https://www.maxmind.com/en/locate-my-ip-address) and also use [WhatIsMyIP](https://www.whatismyip.com/my-ip-information/?iref=homegb), they show me the different locations. So I guess the database for these 2 tools may different and cause this issue.

Hope it can help you.

Comment: Microsoft should mention it on their website site that the City location information is not usable for any practicle puprose or improve the underlying product that supplies that information.
Too bad such a repurted company provide false and misleading information.